# Scrollmagic .to() not working on Fullpage in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js, scrollmagic

I'm having problems changing the background color of an element (".background") using Scrollmagic. I've successfully changed other elements background colors, but this specific one has defeated me. Here is the scenario:

When a user scrolls down to or clicks on the "Studios" navigation link some of the elements will change background colors (most of them work already). I'm specifically trying to change the background color of the "tooltips." These are the boxes that appear if you hover over the navigation dots on the left (there are 5 currently) or top (currently 2 on the Studios section). Each of these tooltips has the "background" class.

When you first load the page and hover over the top dot on the left you should see "Expedition" pop up in a purple box. When you scroll down to Studios it should change this box and others like it to a red box. It doesn't.

Here is a link and relevant code.

[Link to live example](http://tayklin.com/clients/alexllc/)

***Warning*** This is a work in progress. Ignore the fact that a lot of other things don't work. This definitely won't work on mobile or small-width devices.

```
//Studios
var redBG = '#7d1217';
var redLight = '#7d3537';
var redNav = '#fc1925';
function tooltipStudios() {
    jQuery(".backdrop").css({"backgroundColor" : redBG})
}

//Create Studios Timeline
var studiosColor = new TimelineMax()
    .to('#site-header-menu', 0.3, {backgroundColor: redLight})
    .to('#wpfp-navmenu', 0.15, {backgroundColor: redBG})
    .to('#fp-nav ul li a span', 0.3, {backgroundColor: redNav})
    .to('#secnav-studios span', 0.15, {backgroundColor: redLight})
    .to('.dropdown-content li', 0.05, {backgroundColor: redBG})
    .to('#colophon', 0.3, {backgroundColor: redBG})
    .to('.background', 0.15, {backgroundColor: redBG});

// Studio Scene
var studiosScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: '#slide-studios',
    offset: 200
})
.setTween(studiosColor)
.addTo(controller);
```

I've been trying to narrow down what is preventing it from triggering and so far here is what I can think of:

1. The Fullpage plugin has a default setting for color (right now it is the purple) and is preventing any changes somehow. The css it includes is a style tag with ID "wpfp-dynamic-css"
2. .to() isn't the right action to use in the tween. This is my first time using Scrollmagic so I'm learning as I go.

I wanted to see if there were other ways to change the tooltip color successfully and I was able to. You'll notice in the code block i included i have a function called tooltipStudios(). If I use this function as a call() in the tween it will successfully change the color (you can see an example if you go down to the Agency section. It will change the tooltip bg to #000000). However, the color won't change back if you scroll back up to any section like the colors of other elements do when I use .to().

I'm completely stumped at this point. Here is a quick list of some of the relevant plugins/scripts that you may need:

- Wordpress (up to date at the time of writing)
- WP Fullpage plugin (incorporates fullpage.js)
- Scrollmagic (up to date at the time of writing)

Please feel free to ask for any other information/code and I'll supply it.

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to tackle this!

Answer (score 0):

If you read [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions#parallax-doesnt-work-with-fullpagejs) you'll find the answer in this questions:

- jQuery scrollTop function doesn't work
- jQuery scroll event doesn't work

> **Short answer:** use the scrollBar:true option for fullPage.js or autoScrolling:false if you don't want to use the auto-scrolling feature.
>
> **Explanation:** Parallax, as well as many other plugins which depends on the scrolling of the site, listens the scrollTop property of javascript and the scroll event. fullPage.js doesn't actually scroll the site but it changes the top or translate3d property of the site. Only when using the fullPage.js option scrollBar:true or autoScrolling:false it will actually scroll the site in a way it is accessible for the scrollTop property.

Comment: I tried setting scrollBar:true, autoScrolling:false, and every combination of off/on I could and nothing seemed to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Without any reproduction or code regarding fullpage.js is difficult to know, but you should in any case initialize any external plugin in the `afterRender` callback as detailed in the FAQs as well.